# Actualizar automaticamente una columna en la base de datos PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos con 20 registros en mysql phpmyadmin y tengo una columna llamada 'color', cada registro tiene un color por ejemplo "Red$", "Amber$", he visto documentación que se puede crear de esta manera:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status ON SCHEDULE EVERY 45 SECOND 
DO 
UPDATE xbeesend SET colour = Purple$;
```

pero me gustaría que cada 45 segundos cada registro de los 20 cambie a un color diferente, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? o ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde php?.

Saludos.